# I have to login to google each time I close and open the firefox

Tags: firefox

This started happening only after I installed firefox 3.5 on my winxp laptop. Each time I close and open my browser I have to relogin to google (ensuring that stay signed in) is checked. Was some default setting changed in FF 3.5 or have I changed something. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any add-ons installed that interfere or interact with cookies?

Also, is your system time correct?

Lastly, click Tools > Options, and under Privacy, there is a option saying ...

Firefox Will :... (Make sure it says "Remember History"

Comment: +1 For making me open Tools > Options.
Dumb me. I should have figured it out myself. Clear History when FF is closed was checked.

Comment: +1 to Ciaran for noticing! Thanks... Finally at 1K so very happy

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when I used a GMail notifier add-on.  All of the notifier add ons I tried did this.  I ended up using either Digsby, Trillian or the GMail Notifier from Google to get around this.  I've settled on the GMail notifier.

Comment: +1 for gmail notifier, very significant add-on